# ASPNETDB.mdf for MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

Does anyone have or know where I can get a version of the ASP.NET bundled database ASPNETDB.mdf for MySQL?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't exist.  Everything in ASP.Net that uses that database is provider-based.  (Membership, Personalization, Role, etc) If you want to use MySql you have to go find or implement a provider for mysql, and that includes creating the database and tables yourself.