# Convert ASP.NET MDF to MySQL Database?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

How to convert ASPNETDB.MDF mssql database to MySql which works with ASp.NET

Comment: YOU FORGOT TO TURN OFF CAPS LOCK

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274526/aspnetdb-mdf-for-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tool:

*Access to MySQL is a small program that will convert Microsoft Access Databases to MySQL.*
http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Comment: But as Aim Kai commented.. You wont be able to use it in your ASP.NET app.

Comment: Won't a .mdf be from SQL Server Express or Compact not Access?